# Formatting output in bunyan logging

Tags: node.js, logging, timestamp, bunyan

I am experimenting on node bunyan module. As a part of it I would like to know some facts regarding bunyan..

1. Does bunyan facilitate a way to change the order of the contents printed on bunyan logs. For example by default timestamp will be printed at the end...Is there a way to print it at the start? If yes please share with me..
2. Bunyan logs will be logged to a file by specifying the path in the application. Instead of specifying in the application,can we specify somewhere else in the properties file.If so please share how to do that...

Answer (score 3):

For #1, I'm assuming you're using the bunyan-cli. You can change a few things, but I don't think you can change the order. It does have a formatter, and you could use `node index.js | bunyan -o short` to change your output from this:

```
[2015-05-13T22:55:28.613Z]  INFO: App/sampleObject/77405 on host.local: User logged in (reqId=1, user=frank)
[2015-05-13T22:55:28.615Z]  INFO: App/sampleObject/77405 on host.local: User queried DB (reqId=1, user=frank)
```

to this:

```
22:55:15.830Z  INFO App/sampleObject: User logged in (reqId=1, user=frank)
22:55:15.832Z  INFO App/sampleObject: User queried DB (reqId=1, user=frank)
```

I find that more readable.

For #2, you'd want to set up a logging instance the start of your app, from a config file. Something like below:

```
var bunyan = require('bunyan');
var configOptions = require('../path/to/config.json');
var logger = bunyan.createLogger( configOptions );
bunyan.log = logger;
```

There are better strategies for loading a config file, but a single JSON file will work. You might need more options than pure JSON can provide if you want to set up `process.stdout` streams, so a `config.js` file would be better in that case.

In other files, you'd access the log like:

```
var log = require('bunyan').log;
log.info('This is another file.`);
```

Be sure to configure the logger *before* requiring the other files, or the logging object `log` will not be initialized correctly.

> **NOTE:** You can also add a stream to a Bunyan logger dynamically. This is not in their documentation (so maybe use at your own risk), but for a given `logger`, you can make the call `logger.addStream( streamConfigObj )` where `streamConfigObj` is the same object you would use in `stream` or `stream:[]` to `.createLogger`

Comment: Hi Clay,   I am ok with the first answer. I have implemented it in windoes machine and I am getting the output as expected. But when I am trying to run the same node server in raspberry pi I am getting an error stating bunyan not found. sorry to mention that I am not able to understand second answer. can you please explain with an example.

Comment: The second answer, for how to configure bunyan from a config file, basically boils down to "Use data from a config file to create the bunyan log instance". Bunyan must be configured, either the `stream` object, or `streams : [ ]` that is part of the object passed into `bunyan.createLogger`. With that, you can create any file path you want, but *you* must connect your config data to that bunyan call, bunyan won't do it for you. I'll also edit my answer with another approach.

Comment: Can i achieve #1 by passing some param in createLogger function rather than cli?